# Using the Aggregate Framework, how can I embelish a Collection in MongoDB with data from a pipeline (kinda right outer join)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
db.Parent.insertMany([
{ParentName: "MS", Type: "TAA"},
{ParentName: "MS", Type: "TAB"},
{ParentName: "MS", Type: "TAC"},
{ParentName: "MS", Type: "TAD"},
{ParentName: "GP", Type: "TAA"},
{ParentName: "GP", Type: "TAB"},
{ParentName: "GP", Type: "TAC"},
])

db.Mapper.insertMany([
{Type: "TAA", Identifier: "RA"},
{Type: "TAB", Identifier: "SA"},
{Type: "TAC", Identifier: "TA"},
{Type: "TAD", Identifier: "WA"},
])

db.Items.insertMany ([
{Name: "One", Identifier: "RA"},
{Name: "Two", Identifier: "RA"},
{Name: "Three", Identifier: "RA"},
{Name: "Four", Identifier: "SA"},
{Name: "Five", Identifier: "SA"},
{Name: "Six", Identifier: "WA"},
])
```

For a given input parameter of "GP" I want to embelish `Items` with the `Type` from `Parent`,
mapped via `Mapper`, so that the output is as follows.  I want all Items regardless of
whether there are any matches from `Parent`/`Mapper` or not.

```
[
{Name: "One",  Identifier: "RA", Type: "TAA"},
{Name: "Two",  Identifier: "RA", Type: "TAA"},
{Name: "Three",Identifier: "RA", Type: "TAA"},
{Name: "Four", Identifier: "SA", Type: "TAB"},
{Name: "Five", Identifier: "SA", Type: "TAB"},
{Name: "Six",  Identifier: "WA},
]
```

I got as far as selecting the right rows from `Mapper` for a given input of "GP" in `Parent` and got stuck there.

I'm not sure if I could switch the query around and start with `Items` and then insert any matches.

```
db.Parent.aggregate(
{$match: {ParentName: "GP}},
{$project: {Type:1, _id:0}},
{$group: {_id:1, types: {$addToSet: "$Type"}}},
{$lookup: {
  from: "Mapper",
  let: {types: "$types"},
  pipeline:[{
    $match: {$expr: {$in: ["$Type", "$$types"]}}    
  }],
  as: "mapper"
}},
??? Right outer join with Items here ???
).pretty()
```

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8vMRvMGlHRz) what you are looking for? If you are looking for a "right outer join", there should have multiple records/documents for your sample dataset.

Comment: `let: {types: "$types"},` - you define this and use it as `$$types` (not `$types`) in the ` pipeline''s `$match` stage. Refer the MongoDB Manual for the correct usage and examples.

Comment: Thanks @prasad_ - that was a typo on my part when creating this question.  Corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query1

- not nested join(unwind first)
- `lookup` with `Mapper` on `Identifier`
- `unwind` and `project` to keep only what we need
- `lookup` with `Parent` with 2 creterias

  - `"$ParentName" = "GP"`
  - `and same Type`
- `unwind` with `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` to keep those that didn't join also
- `project` to keep only what is needed

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70103240-m)

```js
items.aggregate(
[{"$lookup": 
    {"from": "Mapper",
      "localField": "Identifier",
      "foreignField": "Identifier",
      "as": "joined"}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$joined"}},
  {"$project": {"Type": "$joined.Type", "Name": 1, "Identifier": 1}},
  {"$lookup": 
    {"from": "Parent",
      "let": {"type": "$Type", "indentifier": "$Identifier"},
      "pipeline": 
      [{"$match": 
          {"$expr": 
            {"$and": 
              [{"$eq": ["$ParentName", "GP"]}, {"$eq": ["$$type", "$Type"]}]}}},
        {"$set": {"Identifier": "$$indentifier"}}],
      "as": "joined"}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$joined", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true}},
  {"$project": 
    {"_id": 0, "Name": 1, "Identifier": "$joined.Identifier", "Type": 1}}])
```

Query2

- nested join
- join on `itemIndetifier`
- nested join on type only if `ParentName="GP"`
- unwind with option `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` like above
- final unwind
- project to keep what we need

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70103240-1-m)

```js
items.aggregate(
[{"$lookup": 
    {"from": "Mapper",
      "let": {"itemIndetifier": "$Identifier"},
      "pipeline": 
      [{"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$$itemIndetifier", "$Identifier"]}}},
        {"$lookup": 
          {"from": "Parent",
            "let": {"type": "$Type"},
            "pipeline": 
            [{"$match": 
                {"$expr": 
                  {"$and": 
                    [{"$eq": ["$ParentName", "GP"]},
                      {"$eq": ["$$type", "$Type"]}]}}}],
            "as": "joined1"}},
        {"$unwind": 
          {"path": "$joined1", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true}}],
      "as": "joined2"}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$joined2"}},
  {"$project": 
    {"_id" : 0,"Name": 1, "Identifier": 1, "Type": "$joined2.joined1.Type"}}])
```

*Indexes to work on pipeline lookup you need MongoDB 5, if you you benchmark those 2 on your data, send some feedback if you can on which was faster. I think both queries do what you need.